# Return unique values from an array in PHP without keep first copy of a duplicate

Tags: php, arrays, unique

There are numerous threads on SF where users answer how to return unique values of a PHP array. The prevalent answer is:

`$arrWtihDuplicates = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c']`

`array_unique($arrWtihDuplicates) // will return ['a', 'b', 'c']`

Is there a way to not have `a` returned at all?

Here is why this behavior can pose problems:

Let's come back to `$arrWtihDuplicate`. What if I want to return only duplicate values from this array? This would not work:

```
$arrWtihDuplicates = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c'];
$withoutDuplicates = array_unique($arrWithDuplicates);

var_dump(array_diff($arrWtihDuplicates, $withoutDuplicates));
```

The above would return an empty array - both arrays share the same values so `array_diff` does not see a difference between them.

So to sum up, how can I return array values that do not have any duplicates so that:

`['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c']` becomes `['b', 'c']`

or, conversely

`['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c']` becomes `['a', 'a', 'a']` - having done that 
`array_diff(['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'a', 'a'])` would return **only** true uniques - `b` and `c`.

It seems overly complicated to make such computation in PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use set of PHP functions like as `array_count_values`, `array_filter`, & `array_keys` in order to get the result

```
$arr = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c'];
$result = array_keys(array_filter(array_count_values($arr),function($v){ return $v==1;}));
print_r($result);//['b','c']
```